# Program returning inf?

Tags: c, floating-point

I think the error lies in this line:

```
float bmi = weight * 703 / pow(height, 2.0); // user inputs weight and height and the bmi should be calculated.
```

The thing is, I created a sort of mock program with the values already put in and everything was fine. But when I use scanf() to have the user put in those same values it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    float weight = 105, height = 63;
    float bmi;
    bmi = weight * 703 / pow(height, 2.0);
    printf("%f\n", bmi);
}
```

Both weight and height are floats. When I try to print the bmi I get "inf."

** Edited to show input function and print statement.

```
 printf("Weight? ");
    scanf("%f", &weight);

printf("BMI is %.2f.\n", bmi);
```

The other input statement is essentially the same with the word height replacing weight.

edit: Here is the entire code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    float weight, height;
    float bmi = weight * 703 / pow(height, 2.0);

    printf("Height? ");
    scanf("%f", &height);

    printf("Weight? ");
    scanf("%f", &weight);

    printf("Your BMI is calculated at %.2f.\n", bmi);

    printf("%f\n", height);
    printf("%f\n", weight);


}
```

Comment: The minimal example you give should include the problem. If inputs are giving you trouble, show an example of you taking inputs and the inputs you type in.

Comment: `printf()` the `height` value in addition to `bmi` to see if it is what you expected it to be.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. Having done this, for some reason the program prints the number but adds 6 decimal places to the number, could this have something to do with it. 100 prints 100.000000

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible with the information you have provided.

Comment: Just uploaded the entire code

Comment: What input did you give it?

Comment: I edited something and it is now returning 0.00 instead of inf. But I input wight as 105 and hight as 63

Comment: "I edited something" : Care to share what that was?

Comment: FWIW, instead of `pow(height, 2.0)` I would simply use `(height * height)`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `weight` and `height` uninitialized in:

```
   float weight, height;
   float bmi = weight * 703 / pow(height, 2.0);
```

This is undefined behavior and thats why you get `inf`, in my case I get `0.00`, but anything can happen under UB.

Change to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float weight, height;
    float bmi;

    printf("Height? ");
    scanf("%f", &height);

    printf("Weight? ");
    scanf("%f", &weight);

    bmi = weight * 703 / pow(height, 2.0);
    printf("Your BMI is calculated at %.2f.\n", bmi);

    printf("%f\n", height);
    printf("%f\n", weight);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just started C, have only used python and I never understood initialization. It confuses me as to why a variable would have a preassigned value if none hasn't assigned a value to it. But how to I initialize it??

Comment: If you are under C99 you can put `float bmi = weight * 703 / pow(height, 2.0);` after the second `scanf`

Comment: WRT initialization: in C and many other languages, a variable is just a memory location of the appropriate size. If the variable is not initialized, the variable simply contains the data that was there when the memory location was reserved. That data can be any bit pattern left there from previous use of that same memory location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your variables before you use them.

```
int main ()
{
    float weight, height;
    float bmi;

    printf("Height? ");
    scanf("%f", &height);

    printf("Weight? ");
    scanf("%f", &weight);

    bmi = weight * 703 / pow(height, 2.0);

    printf("Your BMI is calculated at %.2f.\n", bmi);

    printf("%f\n", height);
    printf("%f\n", weight);

}
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure how to initialize. But

Comment: You need to make sure that height and weight have values stored in them before you use them in your calculation. In my example, the height and weight variables have been initialized with the input values received from scanf

Answer (score 0):

```
float weight, height;
float bmi = weight * 703 / pow(height, 2.0);
```

I think you're assuming that this defines the meaning of `bmi`, and that the value of `bmi` will  change when `weight` and `height` change.

I remember making a similar error when I first started programming. Unlike mathematical equations, statements in C are executed in order. You'll soon learn about ways to affect that order, but for a small program like this statements are executed linearly.

An initialization acts like an assignment. This:

```
float bmi = weight * 703 / pow(height, 2.0);
```

does the same thing as this:

```
float bmi;
bmi = weight * 703 / pow(height, 2.0);
```

It sets the value of `bmi` to the result of the expression *at the time it's evaluated*. Since you haven't assigned values to `weight` and `height` yet, their values are garbage, and the result of the expression, assigned to `bmi` is also garbage.  You print that unchanged garbage value later.

If you wanted `bmi` to be something that's evaluated when you refer to rather than when you define it, you *could* make it a function -- but that's not necessary in this case. Instead, just make sure that the value you assign to `bmi` is valid, which means it has to be computed *after* you've assigned values to `width` and `height`.

Drop the initialization on the declaration of of `bmi` and add an equivalent  *assignment* after valid values have been stored in `width` and height`:

```
float weight, height;
float bmi; /* remove initializer */

printf("Height? ");
scanf("%f", &height);

printf("Weight? ");
scanf("%f", &weight);

/* add an assignment here */
bmi = weight * 703 / pow(height, 2.0);
```

As someone else suggested, you could also move both the declaration and the initialization later in the program. (Earlier versions of C had restrictions that made this difficult, and some compilers might still not support it.)