# Why does my calculation give 'inf' instead of a number?

Tags: c, floating-point

This code is meant to compute the mathematical constant *e* by adding inverse factorials:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i, n,a;
    float result=1;
    float sum;
    a=1;
    sum=0;
    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        result=result*i;
        sum = a + (i/result);

    }

    printf("%.2f is the answer\n",sum );
```

}

Instead of giving the value of *e*, it produces `inf is the answer`.

Why do I get `inf` instead of `2.78`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program returning inf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577846/program-returning-inf)

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: The first time through the loop multiples `result` by 0 (as `i` is initialised to 0), returning 0. So `result` will always equal 0. So dividing something by `result` (the next line is `sum = a + (i/result);`) equals infinity.

Comment: Time to step through that with a debugger and see where it goes off the rails.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Or simply run the program by hand

Comment: It's not a great question, but it **is** clear what's being asked: "*Why do I get `inf` rather than the finite value I expected?*".  And the answer is straightforward, too, as evidenced by the existing answers.

Answer (score 3):

The error you mention stems from the fact that you are dividing by `0`.

You say you are trying to find the sum of factorials, but you did

`sum = 1 + 0/0
sum = 1 + 1/0
sum = 1 + 2/0
...
sum = 1 + n/0`

instead of

```
 sum = 0! + 1! + 2! + ... + n!
```

The number of errors is staggering! You don't perform the sum, you introduced a factor to each term where there shouldn't be any, you used the intervers of the factorial instead of the factorial, you added `1` where there shouldn't be any, and you miscalculate factorials because you made `0!` equal to `0` instead of `1`.

Replace

```
result=result*i;
sum = a + (i/result);
```

with

```
if (i)
    result=result*i;

sum = sum + result;
```

A simpler solution it seed the variables with the first term, then loop starting with the second. The following is that solution, using better variable names:

```
int N;
int n;
int n_fact = 1;
int sum = 1;

printf("Enter the number of terms: \n");
scanf("%d", &N);

for (n=1; n<N; ++n) {
    n_fact *= n;
    sum += n_fact;
}
```

---

*[I originally thought you were trying to calculate* e*. In case that might actually be the case, I'm going to leave my original answer here.]*

The error you mention stems from the fact that you are dividing by `0`.

You appear to be trying to approximate *e*, but you did

`e = 1 + 0/0
e = 1 + 1/0
e = 1 + 2/0
...
e = 1 + n/0`

instead of

```
 e = 1/(0!) + 1/(1!) + 1/(2!) + ... + 1/(n!)
```

You made quite a few errors! You don't perform the sum, you introduced a factor to each term where there shouldn't be any, you added `1` where there shouldn't be any, and you miscalculate factorials because you made `0!` equal to `0` instead of `1`.

Replace

```
result=result*i;
sum = a + (i/result);
```

with

```
if (i)
    result=result*i;

sum = sum + (1/result);
```

A simpler solution it seed the variables with the first term, then loop starting with the second. The following is that solution, using better variable names:

```
int N;
int n;
int n_fact = 1;
float e = 1;

printf("Enter the number of terms: \n");
scanf("%d", &N);

for (n=1; n<N; ++n) {
    n_fact *= n;
    e += 1 / n_fact;
}
```